# How to solve "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project"?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am beginner in Maven. When I click `clean & Build` to rebuild my project in netbeans, it throws an error

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) on project xxxx-web: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete D:\Gps2.x\xxxx-web\target\xxxx-web-2.11-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar -> [Help 1]
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Or how to build a war file using maven package?

Comment: try `mvn clean` command

Comment: or `mvn clean install`

Comment: Something is probably still holding a handle on that file, preventing the clean-plugin to delete it.

Answer (score 10):

This usually happens in Windows environments when the target folder is "locked". E.g. when you are running your web application (looks like you do) and want to perform a `mvn clean`. The application server/servlet engine locks the files so that `mvn clean` cannot delete the files because they are locked. Try to run this command when the web application is not running.

Edit: This also may happen if you have the target folder open in explorer or editing a text file from target folder, etc.

Answer (score 0):

in case of Glassfish server you just stop the server and put on clean and build after that you run your project it will definately work.confirm

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows system, close all applications (e.g. file explorer, any file opened in e.g. notepad which is part of the "target" folder etc.). Basically, Maven is trying to Delete the file but as it is "locked" by some other application, Maven can't access it and hence can't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project once and rebuild it. If it is not working just kill the java process and restart the studio

Answer (score 0):

System re-start worked for me.Please try that.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is trying to delete the specific file but it is "locked" by some other application.

Maven can't access it and hence can't delete it.

By killing almost all of the java processes, as I was unable to identify which processes causing this issue, helped me to unlock the file for mvn clean.